# How to import the derived type of an exported function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have two files `myFunction.ts` and `index.ts`.

- `myFunction.ts` exports a function like so:

```typescript
export default (param1: string) => { return true }
```

- `index.ts` imports that function like so:

```typescript
import myFunction from './myFunction'
```

and then I want to use the typings from `myFunction` like so:

```typescript
function bla(aFn: myFunction) {
  aFn('hello')
}
```

However, the compiler gives me a `cannot find name myFunction`.

#### How do I get the typings for the exported function?

As a workaround, you can create and export a type for the function like so:

```typescript
export type MyFunctionType = (param1: string) => boolean
export default (param1: string) => { return true; }
```

And then import like so:

```typescript
import myFunction, { MyFunctionType } from './myFunction';

function bla(myFunction: MyFunctionType) {
  myFunction('hello')
}
```

but then you'd be specifying the type information twice, which is something I would like to avoid...

Comment: Does this work? (in a.ts)  `const a = (param1: string) => { return true; };
export default a;`

Comment: what I tried is `function a(param1: string) { return true; }; export default a;` and that did not work either ...

Comment: Oh I know what the issue is. I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Louy was to some extend right. You need to use typeof to get the type information:

```typescript
import myFunction from './myFunction'

function bla(myFunction: typeof myFunction) {
  myFunction('hello')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing types and default parameters or something.

Type of `a` is `Function`. `a` is not a type by itself. The default param can be specified like this:

```
function bla(aFn = a) {
  aFn('hello');
}
```

If you instead need `aFn` to have a signature similar to `a`, you'll have to specifiy that signature or create an interface for it.

```
function bla(aFn: (s: string) => boolean) {
  aFn('hello');
}
```

Or...

```
interface a { (s: string): boolean; }
function bla(aFn: a) {
  aFn('hello');
}
```

Comment: actually you need to use `typeof a` as I posted in my answer. Thx none-the-less since you pointed me to the right direction ;)

Comment: Don't use `typeof`. It doesn't make sense and is generally a bad practice. Why would you create a function only to read its signature? Create an interface instead.